# ASP.NET - SQL - Retrieving 'contained' objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

So I have 2 tables `Comments` and `Students`. Every comment has a student:
`Comment.StudentId`

I am using POCO generated classes, and it seems to give me the whole Student object inside the  Comment classes when I make a query like so:

```
var query =
    from comment in context.Comments
    where comment.StudentId == properId
    orderby comment.Created
    select comment;
```

So I can access student properties like so `comment.Student.Name`

However, when I copy the results (`query.ToList()` to use outside the method, It gives me an error saying the ObjectContext instance was disposed.

How can I retrieve data from objects contained in objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add .Include("Student") before .ToList()

Comment: IOrderedQueryable doesn't seem to have that function

Comment: from comment in context.Comments.Include("Student")

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Linq uses `IEnumerable`, which defers execution of the query until you try to iterate over the results (as you would by invoking `.ToList()`). If you're calling `.ToList()` "outside of the method" as you stated, then chances are you're disposing of the context, which means the query object is no longer viable.

A quick and dirty hack is to make sure to execute the query once before you dispose of the context:

```
var query =
    (from comment in context.Comments
    where comment.StudentId == properId
    orderby comment.Created
    select comment).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call .ToList() before you exit the method that contains your dbcontext.  That will call the database and fill up your Comment class.  Otherwise when you try and "retrieve data from objects contained in objects" outside of that method, and they have not been loaded, you'll see that the DbContext has been disposed.  This is because EF is trying to "load" or "call the database" AGAIN for those items. Of course, since you're now outside of the method containing the context, EF can't load them.  You should read up on EF's "lazy loading" feature which is turned on by default I think.

You may want make a method that just returns your fully loaded Comment object. Something like this:

```
public class YourDbAccessClass {
    public IEnumerable<Comment> GetCommentsByStudentId(int id) {
        using (YourContextClass context = new YourContextClass()) {
            // Eager load Student with the .Include() method.
            var query = from comment in context.Comments.Include("Student")
                        where comment.StudentId == id
                        orderby comment.Created
                        select comment;

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
protected void ...some method on your view or asp page {
    YourDbAccessClass db = new YourDbAccessClass();
    var comments = db.GetCommentsByStudentId(yourIdVariableHere);

    // Now you can loop through those items without dbcontext.
    // Response.Write is probably a bad example, but you probably get the gist here.
    foreach(var comment in comments) {
        Response.Write("<li>" + comment.Student.Name + "</li>");
    }
}
```